# Python: Sign of the Difference between Two Times

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to determine the sign of the difference between two timestamps in the  format `Y-m-d H:M:S` contained in Pandas dataframe columns.

`dtype` says these are "M8[ns]" and using:

```
sign = numpy.sign(df['time1'] - df['time2'])
```

returns results like:

```
-1 days +23:59:59.999999
```

While I want a simple -1, 0, +1 as `numpy.sign` is supposed to do. Can somebody help me to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert timedeltas to integers:

```
sign = numpy.sign((df['time1'] - df['time2']).values.astype(np.int64))
```

Or:

```
sign = numpy.sign((df['time1'] - df['time2']).dt.total_seconds())
```

Comment: `sign = numpy.sign((df['time1'] - df['time2']).values.astype(np.int64))`

Does what I want. It's these small things that drive me crazy with Pandas. Thanks for the solution.